# Apply Rules to pandas dataframe based on criteria defined in rules table

Tags: python, pandas

I have tbl_df with cols col1, col2, col3, col4, col5,col6. It has about 7million rows
I have corresponding rules_df with some cells with wild card as * as follows. There are about 20 rules:

```
     col1 col2 col3 col4 value
Rule1 E    *     P   *     1
Rule2 B    *     P   *     2
Rule3 S    *     P   *     3
Rule4 *    O     C   *     4
Rule5 F    *     C   S     5
Rule6 E    *     *   *     6
```

While some rows in tbl_df are as follows:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4  col5 col6 
E    X     P   A      S   M
E    X     P   A      S   M    
B    Y     P   E      T   N      
S    X     P   E      T   M   
M    O     C   A      T   N   
F    X     C   S      T   N  
E    Z     M   X      S   N
```

I want to use rules_df and get values for each combination in tbl_df.
So output should look like

```
     col1 col2 col3 col4  col5 col6 value
Row1  E    X     P   A      S   M     1
Row2  E    X     P   A      S   M     1  
Row3  B    Y     P   E      T   N     2 
Row4  S    X     P   E      T   M     3
Row5  M    O     C   A      T   N     4
Row6  F    O     C   S      T   N     5  
Row7  E    Z     M   X      S   N     6
```

So using map_df , 2 rules match Row1 in tbl_df Rule1 and Rule2. Same for Row 6 , Rule 5 and Rule 4. But depending on most restrictive rule,
Need to apply that rule, and then loosening up the criteria and applying henceforth - using waterfall method. I was thinking of iterating over contents of rules_df and applying it on tbl_df. Is there a numpy routine,
or faster vector operation I can perform to apply rules - or may be C-routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have 20 rules, you can just loop through the rules with care:

```
rule_cols = ['col1','col2','col3','col4']
rule_cols

# sort rule so more constraints applied last
counts = rule_df[rule_cols].ne('*').sum(axis=1)
rule_df = rule_df.iloc[np.argsort(counts)]

tbl_df['value'] = np.nan

# iterrows is generally bad/slow, but we just loop over 20 rows so ...
for idx, row in rule_df.iterrows():
    mask = pd.Series(True, index=tbl_df.index)
    has_non_star = False
    for c in rule_cols:
        if row[c] == '*':
            continue
        has_non_star = True
        mask = mask & (tbl_df[c] == row[c])
        
    # sanity check if there is a constraint in this row
    # unlikely to happen
    if has_non_star:
        tbl_df.loc[mask, 'value'] = row['value']
```

Output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6  value
0    E    X    P    A    S    M    1.0
1    E    X    P    A    S    M    1.0
2    B    Y    P    E    T    N    2.0
3    S    X    P    E    T    M    3.0
4    M    O    C    A    T    N    4.0
5    F    X    C    S    T    N    5.0
6    E    Z    M    X    S    N    6.0
```